# How To Authenticate The End User In The PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

There is one report in the PowerBI.

There are two options to embed it.

**A) Private (Website Or Portal) :**

[image: List item]

In this option, The end-user have to enter the PowerBI account credentitals to see the report.

**B) Public (Publish To Web/Public)**

[image]

In this option, The end-user no need to provide the crendentials to see the PowerBI report.

**Query :**
I want to embed the report in my web. If we chose the `Option B`, Then anyone who have the link, Can see the report & It's not secure also. But if we chose the `Option A`, Then the every users will be the login page of the PowerBI in my website and also they must have the PowerBI account to see the report.

So I want to go with `Option A`, But the end-users must not see the login page from the PowerBI. They will automatically should be authenticated by common PowerBI account programarically.

How can I do it? My website is in the ReactJS.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/powerbi-implementation-planning-usage-scenario-embed-for-your-organization

Comment: @Andrey Nikolov, I have used the steps mentioned in the article shared by you. It was helpful for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get authenticate on behalf of user and embed the report.

Refer to my [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/KotanaSai21/powerbi-embedded-React-demo) where I embedded the report in a react app using the `powerbi-client-react` library and getting Embed parameters from Azure Function App.

We have [React Developer Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/React-TS/Embed%20for%20your%20organization) to embed the report, but user needs to login with Master User credentials in order to view embed the report.

For your requirement, where you don't want the user to login, we need to follow service principal authentication, where you will get authenticated on behalf of user using `ClientSecret`. MSAL React only supports public Client. So, we need to use Backend capable of holding secret and to get the Embedtoken, one workaround I tried is using the Azure Function App as implemented in my github Repo.

Comment: @Smit Rathod, LMK if you have any question on the response.

Comment: I have reviewed the samples created by you. It was very helpful in the entire development. I have authenticated the users by using PowerBI APIs. Thanks.